# change drawer item icon to right flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used drawer in the flutter, and I user end drawer to change the direction the drawer,

but I need also change the direction of drawer item icon to right flutter, how can I do it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of ListTile **trailing** property

```
         ListTile(
          title:  Text("text"),
          trailing:  Icon(Icons.account),
          onTap:null,
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using `ListTile` widgets

Try this way

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp( HomeApp());

class HomeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          accentColor: Colors.red),
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageScreen createState() => _HomePageScreen();
}

class _HomePageScreen extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(
        title:  Text("Home"),
      ),
      endDrawer: Drawer(
        child:  ListView(
          padding:  EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          children: <Widget>[
             UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountName:  Text("Nilesh Rathod"),
              accountEmail:  Text("nilesh@gmail.com"),
              currentAccountPicture:  CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child:  Text("Nilu"),
              ),
              otherAccountsPictures: <Widget>[
                 CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child:  Text("Pilu"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
             ListTile(
              title:  Text("Home"),
              trailing:  Icon(Icons.new_releases),
            ),
             Divider(),
             ListTile(
              title:  Text("Profile"),
              trailing:  Icon(Icons.person),
              onTap: () => {},
            ),
             Divider(),
             ListTile(
              title:  Text("Tab Layout"),
              trailing:  Icon(Icons.person),
              onTap: () => {},
            ),
             Divider(),
             ListTile(
              title:  Text("Comman View Demo"),
              trailing:  Icon(Icons.person),
              onTap: () => {},
            ),
             Divider(),
             ListTile(
              title:  Text("Close"),
              trailing:  Icon(Icons.close),
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body:  Center(
        child: Text("Home Screen"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

[image]

Comment: thanks, but can I also move the text to right ?? because I using the right language